# Should the data be calculated in DB server or in CGI process? Which way is better?

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, server

So I am an green hand, when I am coding, I always think that should the data be calculated (for example , in MYSQL, I need to do calculation in script which including 'group by') in DB server or in the CGI procedure? Which way is more better and more efficient?

Actually this stuff confuse me such a long time..

By the way, recently I use PHP coding in my work.

Answer (score 1):

As a rule if you are writing php code to process the data for an outcome which an SQL query could have delivered then this will be slower. You will have to assign to memory much more.

Comment: Hmmm..I see, thanks for the answer